# how to send data to Codeigniter controller in jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm doing a search using CI and Jquery, well i'm very novice to this, this is my first time,
i have done this code but i can't figure out how to send data to the controller and search for a value entered in the text box? can you guys help me to figure this out?

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#search').live('click',function(eve){
    eve.preventDefault();
    $.get('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/search_controller/perform', function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    });     
   });
   });
```

regards,
Rangana

Comment: You really shouldn't have to include PHP in your Javascript file to get the corrent URL... surely relative URL will work here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search').live('click',function(eve){
    eve.preventDefault();
    $.get('/index.php/search_controller/perform/' + $("#your-textbox-id").val(),    
      function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
      }
    );     
  });
});
```

Adding the textbox value to the url should work. Also, I have removed the php code for adding the baseurl. Codeigniter will take care of adding that for you.

You will have to add an argument to the `perform` function of your `search_controller` to pickup the textbox value being passed, or you can use the routing methods to get the parameter in the url (more info over [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html)).